# Facebook Graph API - getting post ID without leading user ID

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the FB Graph API to get a user's posts and render a list in PHP. I'd like to include a link to each post, and I've been trying to generate those links by inserting the "post ID" number into a URL. However, the id returned by the graph API is a two-part number that appears to be in the format `userID_postID`. Is there a field that just contains the post ID without the leading user ID and underscore? The Graph API docs don't seem to be very clear on this.

```
<?php 
  function fetchUrl($url){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);

    $feedData = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch); 

    return $feedData;
  } 

  $profile_id = "PROFILEIDHERE";

  $app_id = "APPIDHERE";
  $app_secret = "APPSECRETHERE";

  $authToken = fetchUrl("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={$app_id}&client_secret={$app_secret}");

  $json_object = fetchUrl("https://graph.facebook.com/{$profile_id}/feed?{$authToken}&limit=10");

  $feedarray = json_decode($json_object);

  foreach ( $feedarray->data as $feed_data )
  {
    echo $feed_data->id;
  }

?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually `USERID_POSTID` makes a complete post id. Just the second part (after the underscore)  is not relevant.

Whenever you try to get the details of that post, the `/USERID_POSTID` will give you the relevant detailed result. If you query just for `/POSTID` the result is limited.

You can try this yourself in [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer)

Comment: thanks – I'd been trying to generate my `<a>` elements using a hardcoded user ID, i.e. "...facebook.com/useridhere/posts/{$feed_data->id}". I hadn't even thought to omit the "/userid/posts/" part of the URL and substitute USERID_POSTID, which makes far more sense.